# Magento2 : URL blocked by CORS policy No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2, permissions, magento2.4.4, cors

i am using google translate for my custom module.i am facing issue on console as per given image.
i tried js code in root script it works but in front page  it returns error.
for reference i have given code of phtml file.

console error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aBuC.png

> Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="store_language">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">vendor_Module::test.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

> vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\test.phtml

```
 <div id="google_translate_element" style="float: left;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit()
        {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement(
            {
                pageLanguage: '<?php echo $bashlanguage; ?>',
                includedLanguages: '<?php echo $lanselected; ?>',
                <?php echo $layouthtml; ?>
            },
            'google_translate_element');
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

> magento_root :- .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

 <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|json)$">

    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Host, Content-Type, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "600"

 </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```